# If I’m applying for an Australian ETA, but I’ve been convicted as a minor once or twice and it got expunged, do I put yes I’ve been convicted?

Tags: australia, eta

I was between the ages of 11-13 when I got arrested for vandalism and had to do some community service. Then I got arrested for trespassing around the same age and I'm pretty sure they just let me off for that because nothing came of it.

When I was joining the military a few years ago, they tried to pull my criminal record from the police station that should have it, and nothing came back. What do I do? What would you do?

Comment: What does the full question say?

Comment: I doubt *(US?)* expungment is recognized under Australian immigration law. I'd suggest you stay on the safe side and apply for a Visitor (600) visa

Comment: What did you tell the military?

Comment: You should check your own criminal record. Being arrested for something is not the same as being convicted for it.

Comment: @DJClayworth If they did community service for it, then they very likely got convicted for the act they did

Comment: Likely, but not certainly. Charges may have been dropped after an agreement and some community service.

Comment: Not legal advice, but in some cases, basic trespassing isn't criminal, but an infraction, like running a stop sign.

Comment: Does your country even make children of this age criminally liable?

Comment: I've learned that a record is never truly "expunged". Many agencies *still* have the records and will say so when asked.

Comment: as a general rule (I don't know about Australia specifically), if you answer "yes" and they wanted "no" then you might have to go to an Australian embassy, explain why you answered "yes" and get a visa the old-fashioned way. If you answer "no" and they wanted "yes", you will never be allowed to go to Australia for a very long time (10 years or more) - you lose, good day sir. Which one is the better risk?

Answer (score 23):

You need to be very clear of the meaning of the word "conviction".   A youthful encounter with the system is a far cry from an adult conviction.

It is quite possible you were diverted into a program where they filed charges and put them on the shelf pending you doing some community service or other reparations, and then dropped the charges. It's easier!  It avoids a bunch of hard problems relating to getting a minor to consent to a plea bargain.  Establishing that an adult plea bargain is valid and consensual, so it can't be appealed later, is a hard problem, actually. Harder with a child.

The exact workings of this are beyond our expertise in travel.se, and you either need to go to law.se and give a lot of personal information, or have a local attorney investigate.  I would recommend the latter.

I would not give a response to Australia until you have, because if you incorrectly admit a conviction that did not happen, you will never be able to un-ring that bell.

Comment: [law.se] would not answer, as they have a policy of "no specific legal advice"  (you can ask about generalities, but not how the law applies in your own specific situation)

Answer (score 14):

The [official PDF help](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/supporting/files/australian-eta-app-industry-guidance.pdf) for the Australian ETA shows the question. And states :

> If the applicant has been convicted of an offense in any country (**including any conviction which has now been removed from official records**) this mean that the applicant has a criminal conviction

> If the applicant has a criminal conviction in any country, they should apply for a Visitor (subclass 600) visa

You *can try* applying for the ETA, but it is extremely likely that you aren't eligible for an ETA now and must apply for a full Visitor (subclass 600) visa

Comment: Unless the community service was part of a pre-trial diversion program, in which case the charges were likely dropped as a matter of prosecutorial discretion and there was no conviction.

Comment: Or part of some child criminality prevention programme, because in many countries children of this age cannot be charged of a criminal offense.

Comment: OP needs a lawyer but what he describes doesn't sound like a *conviction* to me.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава The issue is not whether the OP's country considers a criminal violation by an under-18 person a "criminal conviction" (California, for examine, does not consider criminal law violations by minors adjudged in Juvenile Court a "conviction" — state law refers to them as a "finding"), but is instead whether **Australia** considers such a court finding a conviction.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica I don’t think _any_ country considers a criminal violation by anyone to be a conviction; the violation happens the moment you break the law, while the conviction happens in court, and I at least have never heard of any jurisdiction that conflates the two. I think Vladimir was referring to programmes that ensure cases like this never make it to court at all. The point here is that, since we don’t even know where in the world the asker lives, we have no way of knowing whether they have a conviction in the eyes of either their own country or Australia.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Your point is well-taken. My comment's text would have been more accurate if "...a criminal violation by an under-18 person..." had instead been "...a court finding of a criminal law violation by an under-18 person..."